# Fourier series for square wave

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Could I get some assistance with this? Not sure how to get the solution at all. See image attached.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what a Fourier series is? Do you know the basic formulas for coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the Fourier series of the function $f(x)$:
>   $$f(x)=\frac{\text{a}_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{a}_\text{n}\cos\left(\text{n}x\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{b}_\text{n}\sin\left(\text{n}x\right)\tag1$$

---

1. For $\text{a}_0$ we have:
   $$\text{a}_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\space\text{d}x\tag2$$
2. For $\text{a}_\text{n}$ we have:
   $$\text{a}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(\text{n}x)\space\text{d}x\tag3$$
3. For $\text{b}_\text{n}$ we have:
   $$\text{b}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(\text{n}x)\space\text{d}x\tag4$$

Comment: I always wonder why the cases $a_0$ and $a_n$ are separated.

Comment: @PeterForeman No reason, this is how I studied them. You can combine them of course.

Comment: Yes similarly for me. I rarely see them combined.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Ended up with X(t) = 1/2 + sigma 2/n*pi sin(n*pi/2) * cos(n*t)

Comment: @PeterForeman it's because the $a_0$ and $a_n$ basis vectors don't have the same norm. $a_0$ is twice as big as $a_n$. This is a consequence of $\cos$ being "half" of a complex exponential but a constant is a "full" complex exponential.